# эффект печатания текста с паузой на запятых и точках в unity

Tags: unity3d, текст

вот скрипт что выводит текст из массива

```
    public IEnumerator TextAnimation()
    {
        foreach (var abc in nodes[i].NPS_diolog)
        {
            diolog.text += abc;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(nodes[i].delayTime);
        }
    }
```

вопрос. Как сюда пристроить паузу на запятых и точках.

Comment: я видел что кто-то так делал. но никак не могу найти то видео (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

через пробы я вывел решение.

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text TextArea;// поле вывода текста
    private string TextDiolog;// то что будет выводится

    private string Text;// доп. переменная для проверки на знаки
    private void Start()
    {
        TextArea = GetComponent<Text>();
        TextArea.text = null;
        StartCoroutine(TextAnimation());
    }
    private IEnumerator TextAnimation()
    {
        foreach (var ABC in TextDiolog)
        {
            TextArea.text += ABC;
            Text = ABC.ToString();

            //место где проверяется текст на знаки
            if (Text == (".").ToString()
             || Text == (",").ToString()// знак || означает в программировании или
             || Text == ("!").ToString()
             || Text == ("?").ToString())
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);// время для паузы
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);// время для вывода след. буквы
            }
        }
    }
}
```